# Sendkeys function not working in Windows 10

Tags: vba

Below code part is not working in Windows 10. Actually when I'm debugging line by line it's working. When I run the macro it doesn't work.

```
Sendkeys "%a" - alt+a
```

I have tried this different function also.

```
VBA.sendkeys "%a"
```

I have tried with shell function also.

Can anyone please assist me??

Answer (score 0):

It is not describe in which environment that you are debugging
basically, Sendkeys function will help to send a keyboard event to your application

You can do it with in VBA script, a Winscript vbs file or event in CMD
I found one example which my help you

**CMD:**

```
powershell -c "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('%a')
```